# Am I using the adjective correctly in 'an opportunity to contribute to something meaningful'?

Tags: adjectives, commas

> My genuine, honest intentions are to live up to being the "go-to" person for all tasks related to certain datasets, especially when the information will, in some way, relate to all my direct interests and give me an opportunity to contribute to something meaningful.

Why is 'meaningful' underlined inside my google email?
Is the sentence written correctly?

Comment: Question isn't about resume advice

Comment: @YosefBaskin Thank you. I'll take that into account.

Comment: Is that purely contrived, or where does it come from, please? How does Google e-mail come in to this? I've known people who had to deal with hundreds of applications in a single day and I guarantee all of them would  reject this submission out of hand as being more marketing waffle than anything actually meaningful, because broadly, it isn't.

Isn't the most obvious reason 'something meaningful' might be hi-lighted that 'something meaningful' is more meaningful than any simple 'something'?

Answer (score -1):

It thinks you are trying to "meaningfully contribute to something" instead of "contribute to something meaningful". Recommended action is to keep this wording and ignore the suggestion.

Comment: Really? How would you explain that?